# How i can test local variable in Angular 2 with karma + jasmine?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test with jasmine. The issue I am facing is how to test a local variable using jasmine. I was able to test a global variable but not a local variable.

Here is my function:

```
checkDayIsOpen(): void {
  let isSpecial = false;
     this.items.forEach((item) => {
         if (item.is_open) {
             isSpecial = true;
         }
      });
   if(isSpeciality){
       call another function here...
     }
}
```

I want to test the value of `isSpecial`.

Comment: Can you mention how to tested the global variable?

Comment: as per below answer. I can't test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't test it because it is gone after the call. However, you can test if that other fucntion has been called.

```
describe("Person toString() Test", function() {
  it("calls the getName() function", function() {
    var testPerson = new Person();
    spyOn(testPerson, "getName");
    testPerson.toString();
    expect(testPerson.getName).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: How would we ever test template driven forms then ? if we're unable to grab values out such as the form itself to test validation, etc..

Comment: Test your validator methods, put some values in the form and check if the form is valid, etc. If you really think you need to test a local variable of a method, your method is probably too complex.

Comment: I have found a way of getting the component instance. https://angular.io/guide/testing#debugelement-1 which at explains at the bottom, you can local your local variables via the references.

My usecase is that i have a bunch of custom form controls and I'm using template driven forms instead of the form builder. Now I want to be able to test without modifying my component class, and I feel like I should be able to accomplish this via getting references to what angular hooks up automatically and not using @ViewChild to appease the tests :).

All this means less code and simple tests.